# bash: filter the files where NOT to search

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a script that searches for the specified keywords in specified directories:

```
find $directory -type f -name "*.properties" -exec grep -Fi "$keyword"
```

The problem i faced is that the $directory contains 2 types of files - sample files and config files: config / sample.config. Where sample.config is an example only, thus i'm not interested to include them into the search.
The question is how to exclude these 'sample.*' files out of the results of my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question to exclude sample.config files, add `! -name sample.config` in find commands, for example :

```
find $(<$SRC) -type f -name "*.properties" ! -name sample.config -exec grep -Fi "$keyword" --color {} +
```

however `*.properties` can't match `sample.config` so it will not change the result

Comment: Hi @Nahuel Fouilleul, thanks for your feedback. The exact file names are config.properties and sample.config.properties. Is this possible to join the filters with AND?

Comment: yes the and (-a or -and) is implicit (add parenthesis `\(` `\)` around -o or -or)

Answer (score 1):

Probably 1 command to search `$keyword`, with all 4 kinds of your file types, exclude `sample.*`:

`msr -rp dir1,dir2,dirN -f "\.(properties|pl|xml|ini)$" --nf "^sample\." -it "keyword"`

- Use `-PAC` or `-P -A -C` to remove color and line number etc. to get pure result.
- Use `-l` to just list the file paths and show distribution: count + percentage.

`msr.gcc*` is a single exe tool to search/replace file/pipe in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory, with cross platform versions and OS-bit versions. Built-in doc like: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-CentOS-7.html Vivid-demo, Performance-comparision-with-**findstr**-and-**grep**, test etc. just see the home.

Comment: Thanks @Quanamao. I will test this tool in depths, and perhaps plan its usage in future projects. However, in this task we're not allowed to install any thirdparties. Can you leave your contact info for any clarifications?

Comment: @faceless: Needless to install, just 1 exe file (`msr.exe` / `msr.gcc48` / `msr.cygwin` ) about 1.6MB.  My email is qualiu@microsoft.com. For test, you can see/reference: [vivid colorful feature demo](https://qualiu.github.io/msr/demo/windows-test.html) or  `windows-test.bat` or [linux-test.sh](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/tools/linux-test.sh)

Comment: Oh, those above are **features**/functions test. **Peformance** test result can see comparision with **findstr** (Windows) and **grep** (Linux): [Comaprison on Linux/Cygwin](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/perf/summary-full-Cygwin-comparison.md) and [Comparison on Windows](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/perf/summary-full-Windows-comparison.md).  Hope this small tool can help your daily works.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion of @Nahuel, i've modified it a bit and it started working for me as:

```
find $(<$SRC) -type f -name "*.properties" ! -name "sample.*" -exec grep -Fi "$keyword" --color {} +
```